# Testing Wagtail page views using client.get

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, wagtail

I want to test my views functionality for a Wagtail Page that uses the [RoutablePageMixin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/routablepage.html). I've found that Wagtail includes some [testing functionality](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/testing.html), but I'm trying to check the content on different urls. Although the Wagtail test functions work, testing using `self.client.get` doesn't work -- I get an 404 response. I'm trying the following test:

```
def test_subpage(self):
    response = self.client.get(
        self.page.full_url + self.page.reverse_subpage('subpage')
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200,
                     'Request the open positions page')
```

I assume the error lies in the way in which the page is created. I have used several ways, but cannot find one for which this works. The most intuitive way I found to create the page is the following:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.login()
    parent = Page.get_root_nodes()[0] # Home

    self.assertCanCreate(parent, MyPage, {
        'title': 'Title!',
        'title_sv': 'Title2!',
        'slug': 'test',
        'published': datetime.datetime.now(),
    })

    self.page = MyPage.objects.get(slug='apply')
```

The subpages have been manually tested and do seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to create a page within test code (or any other code...) is:

```
parent = Page.objects.get(url_path='/home/')
page = MyPage(title='Title!', slug='test', body='...')
parent.add_child(instance=page)
```

Note that `Page.get_root_nodes()[0]` will not return your site homepage - the tree root is a non-editable placeholder, and site homepages are usually children of it. You *can* create additional children of the root, but unless you give them a corresponding Site record, they won't be accessible under any URL (which is probably why you're getting a 404 in your test).

Comment: hm, this doesn't really answer the problem of `self.client.get` yielding 404s for any URL that isn't in urls.py though. For instance, if a page a `@route` def that may lead to 400 or 302 responses based on route validity, this solution won't let you verify that `response.status_code` is the one it's supposed to be.